# Windows 7: "Replace All Child Object Permissions" Doesn't Stay Checked

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, properties

I right-click on a top-level folder in Windows Explorer.  I choose Properties > Security tab > Advanced > Change Permissions.  I check "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object" > Apply.  I get a Windows Security dialog that says, "Setting security information on" the list of objects that flashes by.  But now the "Replace all child object permissions" box is unchecked.  What is happening here?

Answer (score 4):

This is not just in Windows 7, this happens in Windows XP and on Windows Server as well. The permissions were already applied and the check box does not stay ticked. It only executes the command once.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to stay checked. Windows NT starting with 2000 supports inheritable permissions, so this operation simply removes all explicit permissions and enables inheritance.

Comment: So if I add a new subfolder, does the command automatically apply to that subfolder, or do I have to repeat the command?

Comment: If you don't believe us, try it and see for yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  What's the answer to my question?

Comment: raywood, did you ever find out the answer to this? I'm running into the same issue where if I add a subfolder or a file into a folder, it doesn't inherit the parent's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as raywood: I checked "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object", and it applied permissions to all objects in the folder. But after this the box did not stay checked (it clears automatically). Consequently when I later moved files to the folder – they did not inherit permissions from the folder, and some users did not have needed permissions.

My workaround is the following: In the same window (Properties -> Security tab -> Advanced -> Change Permissions) I selected a user or the group for which I wanted to have the permissions, then clicked on Edit button. In the next window I picked the permissions that I needed, including the “CHANGE PERMISSIONS” and checked the box "Apply these permissions to objects …", then OK. This check box stays checked (does not clear automatically).